# How to check all listnode fields against a specific value in xslt?

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWB6/2

In this example, I try to match the `<persons>` list whose `<person>.<lastname>`   does not match all other persons inside that list.

```
<root>
    <persons>
        <person>
            <lastname>doe</lastname>
        </person>    
        <person>
            <lastname>done</lastname>
        </person>    
    </persons>
    <persons>
        <person>
            <lastname>name</lastname>
        </person>    
        <person>
            <lastname>name</lastname>
        </person>    
    </persons>
</root>
```

In the 2nd list, the `<lastname>name</lastname>` is always equal. But in the 1st list the lastname differs. So I would expect that the following `xslt` would output `doe`. But it does not:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:for-each select="persons">
            <xsl:variable name="lastname" select="person[1]/lastname"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(person/lastname = $lastname)">
                <xsl:text>lastnames should be the same: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$lastname"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sidenote: I don't want to detect which person exactly has a different lastname. I only want to find out **if** any person in the persons list has a different.

So the question could as well be rephrased to: how to extract all `<lastname>` as a `Set` and check if `set.size != 1`?

Comment: For completeness, you should say whether an empty persons element is considered to match. Different formulations may handle an empty sequence differently. Both `person/lastname != person.lastname` and `count(distinct-values)=1` give false for an empty sequence.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like `count(distinct-values(person/lastname)) = 1` expresses your condition in the rephrase.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to detect which person exactly has a different lastname. I only want to find out if any person in the persons list has a different.

You could perform a simple inequality check (from the context of `persons`):

```
<xsl:if test="person/lastname != person/lastname">
```

This will return true if any `person` has a different `lastname` than any of its siblings: 
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWB6/5

Comment: From performance point of view, would this be superior to the `count(distinct-values))` approach?

Comment: I don't know. Performance questions are processor-specific; you  need to test with yours.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if the construct is unusual then those who develop processors are unlikely to have put any effort into optimising it.